# Online Keyboard Disables When Text is Entered

Tags: jquery, keyboard, textarea

I'm using a slightly augmented virtual keyboard from this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

The Jquery:

```
$(function(){
var $write2 = $('#write2'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false;

$('#keyboard li').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable

    // Shift keys
    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
        $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
        $('.symbol span').toggle();

        shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
        capslock = false;
        return false;
    }

    // Caps lock
    if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
        $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
        capslock = true;
        return false;
    }

    // Delete
    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
        var html = $write2.html();

        $write2.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1000));
        return false;
    }

    // Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

    // Uppercase letter
    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

    // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
    if (shift === true) {
        $('.symbol span').toggle();
        if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

        shift = false;
    }

    // Add the character
    $write2.html(character+ "  " + $write2.html());
    }); });
```

The problem is, when I manually change the textarea, the keyboard gets disabled.  I'm not really sure why and the tutorial didn't really explain that bug.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually change the textarea"?

Comment: When something is typed into the textarea, the online keyboard gets disabled.  So, you can't operate smoothly btwn typing into the textarea AND clicking the online keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using val instead of html

```
$write.val($write.val() + character)
```

Comment: It works now! Just had to update my version of jquery I was using! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: excellent, glad to be of help :) you can now accept the answer :)